# Question about having Salesforce-generated ICS calendar invite organizers perform organizer-like tasks

Tags: visualforce, email, calendar

I am using Salesforce to send ICS calendar invites to contacts in the system.  It works great in general, but I was wondering if anyone has had issues with the designated ICS organizer not being able to do "organizer" things.

A sample situation is:  the ICS file has several attendees (these attendees also are recipients of the SingleEmailMessage).  The first three attendees are contacts in the system (email addresses pulled from Contact):

```
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:P1@company1.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:P2@company1.com
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:P3@company2.com
```

The fourth attendee is a Salesforce user who always needs to be CCed (email address pulled from User):

```
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:P4@company3.com
```

Attendee P4 needs to be the meeting organizer so he can eventually make changes to it, like add attendees or change the time. In the ICS, I made the ORGANIZER row's email address equal to P4's email address:

```
ORGANIZER:mailto:P4@company3.com
```

When the email is sent out to all the recipients/attendees, P4 cannot do organizer tings, like add attendees or change the time, even though the meeting says that P4@company3.com is the organizer.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is it possible to even do this?  I've tried to change P4's attendee role to "CHAIR", but that didn't help.  P4 uses Outlook, so would Outlook integration solve this (I don't think it would).

I also tried to use the `SENT-BY` functionality of `ORGANIZER` but I didn't know if that value has to be the Salesforce email address sending the email.

I also found it interesting that P4 has to have an ATTENDEE row in order for it to show up in his Outlook calendar... Outlook doesn't automatically look at the ORGANIZER value to pull it into the calendar.

Thanks,
Jeff